# CSS Animation: Image moving at the last possible second

Tags: html, css

animation-fill-mode Isnt working...all the info is below.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <img id="main5" src="IMAGES4THEDEVICES/iphone6.png" width="300px" height="300px" style="margin-top: -155%; float: left; margin-left: 12%; position: relative; z-index: 3">

<img id="main5" src="IMAGES4THEDEVICES/comp.png" width="300px" height="300px" style="margin-top: -155%; float: left; margin-left: 20%; position: relative; z-index: 2">
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#main5 {
    -webkit-animation: move5 2s;
    animation: move5 2s;
-o-animation: move5 2s;
-moz-animation: move5 2s;

animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

animation-delay: 4.5s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
-o-animation-delay: 4.5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 4.5;

-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
-o-animation-iteration-count:1;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
animation-iteration-count:1;


text-decoration: none;

font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
margin-top: -9%;



transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;



}

// here



@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}




@-webkit-keyframes move5
{
    from {
        margin-top: -75%;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -20%;
    }
}
@keyframes move5
{
    from {
        margin-top: -75%;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -20%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes move5
{
    from {
        margin-top: -75%;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -20%;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes move5
{
    from {
        margin-top: -75%;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -20%;
    }
}
```

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong. The example can be seen [on my website](http://samtestphp.web44.net/newindex.html)
As you can see in the example, all the other animations (even the text ones) work perfectly fine, and then the very last one is messed up. Yes, I tried doing it seperately (e.g. iphone6.png is #main5, then comp.png is #main6) and it did not work.

You guys need to see it for yourselves on my site, its hard to explain.

Thanks so much, 
Sam (Tyler, The Creator)

Comment: You know you can't repeat IDs...right? Those images have the same ID.

Comment: I just changed it to #main6...same result.

Comment: Probably need to demo it then. A Jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, one moment please.

Comment: Here's the fiddle, it looks terrible, use it for the code only. To see the results, use samtestphp.web44.net/newindex.html

https://jsfiddle.net/rgxgfzyg/7/